# How do i setup Qt with VTK and Cmake on OS x?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, vtk

Hi i've been having alot of trouble trying to set these things up correctly on mac OSx.

Ive downloaded qt, downloaded Cmake and downloaded VTK with qt from the shell on mac. 
However, im having some trouble with a test project and compiling the files in there.

[VTK configuration of cmake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAkP5.png)

Could someone provide some assistance please?

Comment: Could you add your CMakeLists.txt? Nevertheless, when you use `find_package(<package>)`, cmake looks for a file called `Find<package>.cmake` in the known paths. If such a file is not shipped with your cmake-installation, you need to manually create one (or look for one) and add it (e.g., own folder, add it to the searched paths via `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ...)`).

Comment: Do what the error message says. Set VTK_DIR.

Comment: Have you built Qt? Have you built VTK? When you generated your project for VTK did you enable Qt support?

Comment: Its driving me crazy guys, literally been trying to set it up for 2 days

Comment: It's important to understand at least a little how CMake works so you understand the steps you take.

Comment: ive set the VTK_DIR but have since got another error.

CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/vtk/8.0.1/lib/cmake/vtk-8.0/vtkModuleAPI.cmake:120 (message):
  Requested modules not available:

    vtkViewsQt
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/vtk/8.0.1/lib/cmake/vtk-8.0/VTKConfig.cmake:135 (vtk_module_config)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)

Comment: Did you set it to the build folder that you built VTK into? Not the source folder.

Comment: Looks like you missed an option in your CMake setup when you configured VTK.

Comment: Ok drescherjm ive set the correct folder now i think these are the errors

Comment: CMake Error at /Users/Michael/Desktop/VTK/VTKBuild/CMakeFiles/VTKConfig.cmake:115 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /Users/Michael/Desktop/lib/cmake/vtk-8.0/VTKTargets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)

Comment: CMake Error at /Users/Michael/Desktop/VTK/VTKBuild/CMakeFiles/VTKConfig.cmake:119 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /Users/Michael/Desktop/lib/cmake/vtk-8.0/vtkModuleAPI.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


CMake Error at /Users/Michael/Desktop/VTK/VTKBuild/CMakeFiles/VTKConfig.cmake:135 (vtk_module_config):
  Unknown CMake command "vtk_module_config".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)

Comment: drescherjm where you referring to ccmake .. on shell terminal?
There isnt an option for Qt support on there

Comment: drescherjm Ive edited the thread and added an image of my current configurations for VTK build, is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: I think VTK_GROUP_Views needs to be enabled for vtkViewsQt. I may be wrong however. Because of a dependency problem (need to port an old library that was written from someone else) I am stuck with a much older version of VTK.